# how to install python2.7 version pip?

Tags: python, pip

I tried `python -m pip install six` but this not work.
So I tried to install python2.7 version pip.
But Linux says already installed pip but this pip's version is python3.6
Also `easy_install` not working

I want to install python2.7 version pip.
How to install python2.7 version pip?
Should I erase pip and reinstall python2.7 version pip? or are there another methods?

Comment: "but this not work" What happened? Did you get an error?

Comment: "But Linux says" what does it say exactly? Which distribution and version? What did you run exactly? There isnt a single answer here, it depends on a lot of information we will need to know first.

Comment: Try running `python -m ensurepip` first.